# Looking for the word that means "You believe other people are like you"

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember this applying in marketing and history, where people tend to think that the beliefs of others are similar to their own, often leading to mistakes when developing advertising campaigns, political messaging, etc.

> "Due to Adam's xxxx, he believed that everyone shared his passion for astronaut fan fiction."

Comment: Living in a bubble

Comment: 'solipsism', perhaps, but it's not an exact match

Comment: "Due to 'The Donald' effect, he believed that..."

Answer (score 4):

Heavily influenced by @Graffito's answer and [another ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44337/are-egotistical-and-egocentric-synonyms) ...

> **Egocentrism** is the inability to differentiate between self and other. More specifically, it is the inability to untangle subjective schemas from objective reality; an inability to understand or assume any perspective other than their own.
>   - [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egocentrism)

Answer (score 0):

Consider **egotism**.

> Definition :
>
> - the feeling or belief that you are better, more important, more talented, etc., than other people.
> - an exaggerated sense of self-importance,  an inflated feeling of pride in your superiority to others

Example: *As leaders strive to improve their leadership, they use their self-confidence to guide and sustain them through the learning. Those who believe they need no improvement suffer from* egotism. *Those they lead suffer in it.*